# 'there exists some object $x$, such that ....' statements

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have a question about mathematical English in these statements we get in basic quantification problems, it sounds to me like $x$ is some particular constant named $x$ so under this interpretation $x$ -> some number for which $P(x)$ is true, implying to me (at least) that it's unique. I assume this an incorrect reading of the statement?

Is the correct reading that there exists (at least one value of the variable in our domain of discourse) $x$ such that $P(x)$, so an existentially quantified statement? Allowing for the existence of multiple values.

Comment: The standard interpretation of the [Existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) is: "some", i.e. "there is at least one".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA best reading is 'there is at least one value of our variable $x$...'? I guess in natural language you would be giving the name the name $x$ to a temporarily constant term, but logic is very different.

Comment: The scope of $x$ in "There is $x$ (in $U$) such that $P(x)$" is the "inside" of that proposition. For us, "outside", there is no object being called $x$. Although it is better not to do, because it can cause confusion, the name $x$ could be used again outside for anything else.

Comment: @user85667 is this because it is bound?

Comment: @JohnDouma Yeah, I have realised this and feel like an idiot to be honest...It's just more to do with the english of it and how I've interpreted it, like $x$ is a real number doesn't mean $x$ is a *particular* real number at all times.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a proposition like () without any quantifiers then  is a free variable. It is not a constant.

The value of  is contingent upon the value of . That is different than the existential quantifier which asserts that there is an  that makes the proposition true.

For example, let $P(x)$ be $x+5=7$. Then, assuming we are talking about integer addition, the value $x=2$ makes the proposition true and other values of $x$ make it false.

That is different than $\exists xP(x)$ which asserts that there is an element that makes the proposition true.